# How to show and hide the titlebar on the fly of an MDI frame?

Tags: mfc, mdi, win32gui

I've been looking around and I've not been able to find any solutions that work.

I've tried to use all of these without success:

```
GetMDIFrame()->ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);
GetMDIFrame()->ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0, SWP_DRAWFRAME|SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, ::GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_THICKFRAME));
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, ::GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME)
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the MDI frame's titlebar?  No text or bar (this includes not having the minimize, maximize and close buttons), just a thick border to be able to resize it.

I also happen to be using BCG ribbons as apparently that makes a difference in how it is rendered.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the fly"?  And can you show an image of what you want?

Comment: @rrirower: "On the fly", First definition [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+fly)  __while something or someone is operating or moving. *I'll try to capture the data on the fly*.__.  An image?  I want to have a MDI frame (the main window of an MDI application) to have a title bar one moment and no titlebar the next.  Is an image really necessary?

Comment: Depends on whether you want help.  Do you want to remove the caption text and keep the the frame style, or, change the frame style AND remove the text?  Your description was not clear.  At least, not to me...

Comment: @rrirower, Oh, I see.  I'd like to keep the frame style, but lose the titlebar.  No text or bar (this includes not having the minimize, maximize and close buttons), just a thick border to be able to resize it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is only valid if you use the MFC Ribbon Bar implementation or the BCG implementation.
The major reason why the style flags do'nt effect a ribbon bar implementation is that the ribbon bar draws its own NC area. There is in fact no "Window caption".

You need to initialize your CMFCRibbonBar with the bReplaceFrameCaption set to FALSE.

```
CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
     : m_wndRibbonBar(FALSE)
{
```

Overwrite CMainFrame:PreCreateWindow and set the styles you want.

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
  if( !CBCGPMDIFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
    return FALSE;

  cs.style = WS_POPUPWINDOW;

  return TRUE;
}
```

This results in the effect you want
[image]

Comment: But can I turn it on and off at will?  How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry to say but the simple answer is: No! (As far as I can see) Look into the source (BCG+MFC), the variable m_bReplaceFrameCaption is declared as const BOOL and so it is only definable once upon construction. So you can turn it on or off during the construction of your program... I never tried to destroy an already constructed ribbon bar and try to recreate it. This would be the only chance to solve this. Also the function IsReplaceFrameCaption isn't virtual and not overridable...

Comment: Hrm. Thanks anyway. :(

Comment: Wait! Could this be done for the child?  I.e. could I remove the titlebar of the child in a similar manner?

Comment: The child? What child do you mean. The frame is drwan in the non Client area of the CMainFrame window.

Comment: Never mind. The app I'm maintaining is kinda screwed up with weird crap.  Don't ask.  The long and short of it is that we have a ribbon in the MDIFrame and one in the MdiChildWnd.  I had to remove the titlebar of one of these and hide the ribbon of the frame. By turning off bReplaceFrameCaption for the Ribbon's constructor of the child, I was able to remove it's titlebar in maximized mode.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?  The following code produces what you see in the image below.  I chose an event in the child window to demo the code.

```
void CChildFrame::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
    {
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    CMDIChildWnd::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);

    CMDIFrameWnd* pFrame = GetMDIFrame();
    pFrame->SetWindowTextW(_T(""));
    pFrame->ModifyStyle(WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 0);
    pFrame->ModifyStyle(WS_MINIMIZEBOX, 0);
    pFrame->ModifyStyle(WS_SYSMENU, 0);
    }
```

And the result is....

[image]

Comment: No, not really.  I don't want the title bar at all.  Not just blanked out.

Comment: I think you might be out of luck.  Modifying the other styles tends to corrupt the window (eg. the main menu goes missing).

Comment: Actually, you may be able to try re-sizing the window rect to remove the space for the title bar.  It's just crazy enough to work.

Comment: Actually, I don't care about the menu.  I'm using ribbons and the main ribbon will have to vanish anyway.

Comment: Um, what do you mean about re-sizing the window rect?  Could you explain or show example?

Comment: Never mind.  I just tried something and it didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62438/discussion-between-adrian-and-rrirower).